# How to show rows of a table as columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `LANGUAGE`:

```
CREATE TABLE LANGUAGE
(
    LANGUAGE_ID nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO LANGUAGE (LANGUAGE_ID)
VALUES ('de-DE'), ('en-EN'), ('de-US'), ('fr-FR'), ('es-ES');
```

and a table `TRANSLATION` which contains all translations of a TEXT_ID in several languages:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSLATION
(
    TEXT_ID nvarchar(20), 
    LANGUAGE_ID varchar(10), 
    TRANSLATION varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO TRANSLATION (TEXT_ID, LANGUAGE_ID, TRANSLATION)
VALUES
    ('wire', 'de-DE', 'Draht'),
    ('wire', 'en-EN', 'Wire'),
    ('wire', 'en-US', 'Wire'),
    ('wire', 'fr-FR', 'fr:Draht'),
    ('wire', 'es-ES', 'es:Draht'),
    ('brush', 'de-DE', 'Buerste'),
    ('brush', 'en-EN', 'Brush'),
    ('brush', 'en-US', 'us_Brush'),
    ('screw', 'en-US', 'Screw');
```

As a result I want to get a list of all translations of a `TEXT_ID` in a single row:

```
TEXT_ID     de-DE       en-EN       en-US       fr-FR       es-ES
--------------------------------------------------------------------
wire        Draht       Wire        Wire        fr:Draht    es:Draht
brush       Buerste     Brush       us_Brush
screw                               Screw
```

Is there a pure SQL way to do that?

Currently I am using SQL Server. But potentially we want to migrate to another database.

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5db39/6)

Comment: if number of languages is unknown, then you can start to google "dynamic pivot".If it is defined, then pivot

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

We can try a pivot query with the help of some calendar table logic.  First, build an intermediate table of all keywords and languages.  Then, join this to the `TRANSLATION` table and pivot.

```sql
SELECT
    t.TEXT_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.LANGUAGE_ID = 'de-DE' THEN tr.TRANSLATION END) AS [de-DE],
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.LANGUAGE_ID = 'en-EN' THEN tr.TRANSLATION END) AS [en-EN],
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.LANGUAGE_ID = 'en-US' THEN tr.TRANSLATION END) AS [en-US],
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.LANGUAGE_ID = 'fr-FR' THEN tr.TRANSLATION END) AS [fr-FR],
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.LANGUAGE_ID = 'es-ES' THEN tr.TRANSLATION END) AS [es-ES]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TEXT_ID FROM TRANSLATION) t
CROSS JOIN LANGUAGE l
LEFT JOIN TRANSLATION tr
    ON tr.TEXT_ID = t.TEXT_ID AND
       tr.LANGUAGE_ID = l.LANGUAGE_ID
GROUP BY t.TEXT_ID;
```

Note that if you need a dynamic number of columns, then you might have to resort to dynamic SQL, which basically means writing SQL Server code to generate a query.